# How to use exprtk to evaluate an equasion as bool?

Tags: c++, exprtk

I'm trying to run this code:

```
exprtk::parser<bool> parser;
exprtk::expression<bool> expression;
parser.compile("5 > 6", expression);
std::cout << expression.value() << "\n";
```

But I get this error:

```
'exprtk::expression<T>::operator T(void) const': member function already defined or declared
```

On VS 2019. This doesn't happen when I use other data types. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/):

> `exprtk::expression<NumericType>`
>
> Note: NumericType can be any floating
> point type. This includes but is not limited to: float, double, long
> double, MPFR or any custom type conforming to an interface comptaible (sic)
> with the standard floating point type.

`bool` is not a floating-point type.

Comment: I see, so the only way would be to see if the result is non-zero?

Comment: @GameBoss9000, `5 > 6` return `0`, and `6 > 5` returns `1`. I _think_ the library converts true to 1, and false to 0.